# Test case failing regarding border

Tags: css, html

This is a Lab I am doing with Udacity(Trading Cards). I am facing an error while submitting the project.
I gave the border to entire card but test case result shows I didn't give the border.
I put the entire card inside the div

`<div class="animal-whole">`

and put this css which does put the border around the entire card. But I am still getting test case result as failed

```
  .animal-whole{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

I have attached the test results with the whole HTML CSS code

[Image of test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNnzG.png).

This is the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <title>Building the Prototype</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <!-- start -->
            <div class="animal-whole">
                <div class="animal-name">
                    <h1>Dog</h1>
                </div>

                <img id = "imgId" src="http://www.printesta.com/image/cache/catalog/new/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher-780x520.jpg" alt="dog" width="300px;">

                <div id="card" class="animal-info">

                    <p  id="interesting-fact">A layer of mucus on the dog's skin makes it immune to the fish-eating anemone's lethal sting.</p>
                    <ul id="facts">
                        <li id="dogBorder"><span>Scientific Name</span> Dog</li>
                        <li><span>Average Length</span> 40 centimeters</li>
                        <li><span>Average Lifespan</span> 15 years</li>
                        <li><span>Habitat</span>: I dont know</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p id="summary">Bright orange with three distinctive white bars, clown anemonefish are among the most recognizable of all reef-dwellers. They reach about 31 centimeters in length, and are named as Dog</p>
            </div>
            <!-- end -->

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the CSS file

```
#interesting-fact{
    font-style: italic;
}

li{
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none;
}

#imgId{
    width: 300px;
}

#imgId{

 padding: 5px;
}

.animal-info{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding:5px;
}

.animal-name{
    padding: 5px;
}

.animal-whole{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Try applying this class on the div with id "container".

Comment: hey, this works can you post as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Answer posted!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply class `animal-whole` on the div with id `container`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <title>Building the Prototype</title>
<style>
    #interesting-fact{
    font-style: italic;
}

li{
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none;
}

#imgId{
    width: 300px;
}

#imgId{

 padding: 5px;
}

.animal-info{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding:5px;
}

.animal-name{
    padding: 5px;
}

.animal-whole{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <!-- start -->
            <div class="animal-whole" id="animal-whole">
                <div class="animal-name">
                    <h1>Dog</h1>
                </div>

                <img id = "imgId" src="http://www.printesta.com/image/cache/catalog/new/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher-780x520.jpg" alt="dog" width="300px;">

                <div id="card" class="animal-info">

                    <p  id="interesting-fact">A layer of mucus on the dog's skin makes it immune to the fish-eating anemone's lethal sting.</p>
                    <ul id="facts">
                        <li id="dogBorder"><span>Scientific Name</span> Dog</li>
                        <li><span>Average Length</span> 40 centimeters</li>
                        <li><span>Average Lifespan</span> 15 years</li>
                        <li><span>Habitat</span>: I dont know</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p id="summary">Bright orange with three distinctive white bars, clown anemonefish are among the most recognizable of all reef-dwellers. They reach about 31 centimeters in length, and are named as Dog</p>
            </div>
            <!-- end -->

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#interesting-fact{
    font-style: italic;
}

li{
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none;
}

#imgId{
    width: 300px;
}

#imgId{
    padding: 5px;
}

.animal-info{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
}

.animal-name{
    padding: 5px;
}

.animal-whole{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation of what you did exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <title>Building the Prototype</title>
 </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <!-- start -->
                <div class="animal-whole" id="animal-whole">
                    <div class="animal-name">
                        <h1>Dog</h1>
                    </div>

                    <img id = "imgId" src="http://www.printesta.com/image/cache/catalog/new/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher-780x520.jpg" alt="dog" width="300px;">

                    <div id="card" class="animal-info">

                        <p  id="interesting-fact">A layer of mucus on the dog's skin makes it immune to the fish-eating anemone's lethal sting.</p>
                        <ul id="facts">
                            <li id="dogBorder"><span>Scientific Name</span> Dog</li>
                            <li><span>Average Length</span> 40 centimeters</li>
                            <li><span>Average Lifespan</span> 15 years</li>
                            <li><span>Habitat</span>: I dont know</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <p id="summary">Bright orange with three distinctive white bars, clown anemonefish are among the most recognizable of all reef-dwellers. They reach about 31 centimeters in length, and are named as Dog</p>
                </div>
                <!-- end -->

            </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS file and This is the HTML file

```css
/* add your CSS here */
#interesting-fact{font-style:italic;}
#facts{list-style-type:none;}
span{
  padding: 10px 50px 20px;
  font-weight:bold;}
h1{
  padding: 10px 50px 20px;}

#container{
  padding: 1px 5px 2px;
  border:3px solid black;}
#card{
  padding: 1px 5px 2px;
  border:3px solid black;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Building the Prototype</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Uromastyx</h1>
    <!-- photo credit: wikipedia.org, image taken by Ritik -->
    <img style="width:300px"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Blumeng%C3%A4rten_Hirschstetten_2016-02-21_Dornschwanzagame_%28Uromastyx_geyri%29_c.jpg/1024px-Blumeng%C3%A4rten_Hirschstetten_2016-02-21_Dornschwanzagame_%28Uromastyx_geyri%29_c.jpg" alt="Uromastyx">
    <div id="card" class="animal-info">
      <p id="interesting-fact">Uromastyx is a genus of African and Asian agamid lizards, the member species of which are commonly called spiny-tailed lizards, uromastyces, mastigures, or dabb lizards. Lizards in the genus Uromastyx are primarily herbivorous, but occasionally eat insects and other small animals, especially young lizards. They spend most of their waking hours basking in the sun, hiding in underground chambers at daytime or when danger appears. They tend to establish themselves in hilly, rocky areas with good shelter and accessible vegetation.
</p>
      <ul id="facts">
        <li>
          <span>Scientific Name</span>: Uromastyx
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Length</span>:10 centimeters
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Lifespan</span>: 15 years
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Habitat</span>: Africa and the Middle East
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p id="summary">Uromastyx is a genus of African and Asian agamid lizards, the member species of which are commonly called spiny-tailed lizards, uromastyces, mastigures, or dabb lizards. Lizards in the genus Uromastyx are primarily herbivorous, but occasionally eat insects and other small animals, especially young lizards
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great job!
You have successfully completed the Lab! Please proceed to review your work in order to mark this Lab as complete.

Comment: Some tests failed: